Does Musk have a political agenda in meeting with Italian politicians?
The latest show of interest was yesterday
“Musk presents award to Meloni, hails PM's 'incredible job'”
But there have been other occasions recently and last year where he and some of his sons were guests at Atreju, an annual meeting organised by the right wing  parties.
Not to mention his comments on the low birth rates in Italy.
From: Euronews.com

Elon Musk and Giorgia Meloni: What could an alliance between the divisive figures mean for the EU?

Musk is increasingly using X, formerly Twitter, to express his support for former US President Donald Trump in the upcoming presidential election in November. And there are signs that Italy is next in his sights.


Why is he so active in the political scene in Italy?

Why not? To lift the question above trivia status, what makes an interest of Musk special or important? He is not even an elected politician. Can we learn something about politics by this?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution - Musk is not an ordinary citizen, and it appears he will be in next Trump’s government if he wins the election. Is all this politics?

@user66974 Only tangentially in my eyes. He is politically an ordinary citizen at the moment or is he officially nominated for anything? Just look at the answer and ask yourself what you have learned about politics and what about the personal likes of Musk, who isn't a politician. Or look at the tag you choose. What is the connection to political theory?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution - the perception from Italy is quite different. He was almost unknown here and now he is present  in political issues of the current government. I understand that from an American perspective you don’t give a ..  for him…but people here ask…what is he really after in politics? Maybe time will tell!!

Saying Musk is just an ordinary citizen because he's not running for, or in, office is like saying the Koch brothers or the Heritage Foundation aren't relevant subjects for this forum.  Musk has an outsized influence due to his legion of fans and having his own personal social media network and he is not in any way shy about promoting things he likes and denigrating those he doesn't which is very often political in nature.

@Gio Sure, but then you can take any somewhat eccentric media figure/billionaire and their personal interests and ask why. This would result in lots of questions and one has to draw a line somewhere. To me it's not yet reached here. Also because it's too unspecific. Interest in a country is hardly something surprising. Maybe if there was something more specific. To me it's simply not enough politics involved and too casual, if you understand what I mean. I mean, what implications does Musk interest in Italy has apart from some comments and some visits.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution If these eccentric billionaires and large media owners try to influence politics than they become a matter of politics. The problem is that this kind of politics is a lot less structured (and often a lot less legal). So while technically a matter of politics it's simply hard to give a good answer that doesn't resort to speculation

@haxor789 True. However, a good answer can be provided by including political commentary from Italian politicians and political analysts. I am voting not to close this question.

But then the current version of the question is a simply yes/no, which unless he said so himself, can hardly be answered. It's really hard to ask something specific and not simply ask: Elon Musk, what is he up to?

I'm pretty sure stopping immigrants makes the list.

"He thinks that Europe in particular is headed toward a “civil war” due to the arrival of refugees from other continents."

OTOH Meloni says she actually failed to stop that.
I guess he just finds her beautiful.
Not to downplay their other shared interests, in no particular order:

stopping AI
making babies
stopping the "woke mind virus".


Ah, yes, Musk wants to stop artificial intelligence so much that he spends billions of dollars to create the conservative substitute to Chat-GPT. Very believable, I'm sure.

Also, I am sure he believes that immigration is bad. After all, one can't have immigrants coming from countries like South Africa and siphoning up all the money in a country, right? Undoubtedly, they will start taking billions in government handouts. Or even worse, maybe they will start buying European or American electric car, aerospace and social media companies to impose their scary foreign values.

@Obie2.0: can't have that many words. Not Twitter. Meloni also spends (someone else's) money on AI. And wants to stop it from stealing jobs.

Like here's a billion dollars for "an Italian way to artificial intelligence" and "I am hugely concerned about the impact (of AI) on the labour market. Today we are faced with a revolution where (human) intellect is in danger of being replaced."

I'm sure every AI-displaced middle class worker will get a job to Grok Tweets, the Italian way!

Making babies is an interesting point. Right wing parties in Italy are furiously against surrogate motherhood, something Musk has resorted to, if  I am not wrong.

@Gio: fair point, but like with the other issues, it doesn't mean they [Musk and Meloni] agree 100% on all the details. BTW, the attack on surrogacy is a way to attack gay families. Which is actually related to the 3rd point.

Latest: https://www.reuters.com/world/elon-musk-says-he-is-not-having-affair-with-italys-meloni-after-mutual-praise-2024-09-25/
